# Polynomials indeterminate (example)

Tags: logic, polynomials

I have encountered a polynomial problem. I checked out the answer but it turned out to be very confusing. It's just enough to focus on a separate part of it as the rest of the hypothesis has nothing to do with my question and is futile to be mentioned. We have a polynomial $h\in \mathbb C[X]$ and that $|h(x)| \le 1$ for any $x\in \mathbb R$. It can thus be written as $h(X)=h_1(X)+i×h_2(X)$, where $h_1,h_2\in \mathbb R[X]$. For $x\in \mathbb R$ we obtain that $|h(x)|^2=h_1^2(x)+h_2^2(x)$. We deduct that $h_1(x)=a\in \mathbb R, h_2(x)=b\in \mathbb R, a^2+b^2 \le 1$. What I can't figure out is why after that they say that it results $h(X)=a+i×b$. I mean, they have proved all those things only for $x\in \mathbb R$, not for an indeterminate, so how is it possible to generalize that? I hope you could help me to understand. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're talking about those notations,then I don't know why they were used.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that if $h_1(X)$ and $h_2(X)$ take bounded values on $\mathbf R$, they are *constant* polynomials (as *formal* polynomials), not only as *polynomial functions*, simply because if yoou write them as
$$h_i(X)=c_0+c_1X+\dots +c_nX_n,$$
then $h_i(x)\sim_\infty c_nx^n$, so if $n>0$, it is not bounded.

Comment: what do you mean by "constant polynomials as formal polynomials" ?

Comment: And what is this symbol:\sim_\infty?

Comment: I meant they're constant when they're considered as polynomials (in the indeterminate $X$), not as polynomial functions.

Comment: It is asymptotic equivalence of functions. Didn't you see some Asymptotic Analysis?